# Sharepoint calculated column IF function - Syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

No matter which syntax i use, sharepoint throws me a syntax error on IF function.

here is what i have tried so far

```
= IF ( [colA] = "dddd"; "yes" ; "no" )
= IF ( [nr1] < [nr2]; "yes"; "no")
= IF ( [colA] = "ddd", "yes", "no")  -my localization should use " ; "
= IF ( [colA] ='ddd'; 'yes'; 'no')
```

I can't figure out what's wrong, can this be something that is restricted from Sharepoint Admin in the enviroment?

Comment: Strange....Assuming you have a single line of text column with display name `Column1`. Try using this: `=IF([Column1]="ABC";"OK";"Not OK")`. Also, return the data type of your column as "Single line of text".

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `,` instead of `;`.

Also dont give space after If. Try these:

```
= IF([colA]="dddd","yes","no")
```

```
= IF([nr1]<[nr2],"yes","no")
```

let me know if it works. I used comma and it works fine.

Comment: please see line 3, where i stated my localization. I have tried commas   :)

Comment: =IF([tal1]=[tal2],1,2), =IF([tal1]=[tal2],"1","2") - throws syntax error same with ;

Answer (score 0):

Official document:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a

```
=IF(Title="1","yes","no") should be ok.
```

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: Tried it both with , and ;  my localization is ; and i have other calculated columns that works with ;  it just seems that IF doesnt want to work. I will have a meeting with our software partners in September, it must be something in the enviroment thats not right.